# How can I route MIDI between two tracks?

Tags: midi, logic-pro

please excuse my poor use of terms. I'm brand new to Logic from Reaper.

Logic Pro X has a feature whereby you play something in MIDI and it tells you the chord up at the top of the screen (in the transport?). I think that I read somewhere that this works on 'all input and output MIDI signals'...so, when I play something live on a keyboard, I can see what chord it is, but I can't get it to do it when playing back something that I've previously recorded. This would be handy, because I record a lot of improv, and it would be great to play it back and see the chords so as to put in, say, a bass line.

I'm wondering, if I could route the MIDI from the original track to a new, 'output' MIDI track, then perhaps Logic might display the chords? I know that this routing can be done quite simply on Reaper, but I couldn't figure out the Logic method. Can someone please explain?

Thanks in advance.

-- edit -- 
Ok, I've been playing around with Logic for night number 2. I think that the simpler way to ask this question is, "Logic can name my MIDI chords as I play them, how can I have it show me the chords of a MIDI track that I'm playing back?".

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer in the Logic User Group forum.

http://www.logic-users-group.com/forums/threads/can-i-have-logic-show-me-the-chords-of-a-midi-track.10047/#post-50218

The chord display reads the midi information before it arrives at the sequencer (actually from the physical input) - what you would need to do is reassign that track (or copy the track ) to an external instrument object (or track) - and route it out the Iac bus. Now when you play the track back. The midi data is sent out the external instrument - through the Iac bus and re- enters logic via the physical input - where the chord display grabs it - interprets it and displays it - during playback.